# Derby: bulk import doesn't set AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: java, import, jpa-2.0, derby

Say I've got the following `table`, generated by `Eclipselink`.

```
CREATE TABLE "ACCOUNT" ("ID" BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), "DTYPE" VARCHAR(31), "EMAIL" VARCHAR(255));
```

Next I will import bulk from a file, containing:

```
1,"admin_","myemail@domain.com"
2,"user_","anotheremail@domain.com"
3,"user_","yetanotherone@domain.com"
```

The import is succesful, using `ij tool` from `Apache` in conjunction with `SYSCS_UTIL.SYCS_IMPORT_TABLE()`.

Next I will create a user through `JPA2`. This results in:

```
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL130406103359120' defined on 'ACCOUNT'.
```

Without running the import I can create a user just fine. Seems to me the import doesn't consider the `AUTO_INCREMENT` function as specified in the table. I shouldn't need to update `AUTO_INCREMENT` to `4` using `ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT AUTO_INCREMENT = 4;`, should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do the import, do:

```
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 4
```

See this link: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html#rrefsqlj81859__rrefsqlj37860

Comment: Hmm ok, too bad this isn't part of the function. Though I understand in this should be implemented differently in many cases. Thanks for the link to documentation too!